# wlan0 is missing, shows lo instead (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, drivers, realtek

I've tried all the solutions I've found on the internet but none of them have worked.

In my laptop, I have a Realtek RTL8723AE wireless card. It was not getting consistent connections, so I was trying all the solutions I could find. I'm pretty sure one of them disabled wlan0.

I looked at the owners manual for my computer, and it says that "Pressing FN + F8 repeatedly will turn on or off the wireless card". Doesn't work.

Here is iwconfig:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

lshw -c network

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 13
       serial: 8c:89:a5:0e:a5:64
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.0.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:48 memory:f7900000-f793ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7800000-f7803fff
```

And interesting thing, doing

```
   dmesg | grep rtl
```

Didn't show anything similar to "loaded firmware". Output instead:

```
[   12.809572] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_set_sw_chnl_cmdarray (err 0)
[   12.809577] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_set_bb_reg (err 0)
[   12.809584] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_calculate_bit_shift (err 0)
[   12.809588] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_rf_serial_write (err 0)
[   12.809593] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_path_adda_on (err 0)
[   12.809602] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_save_mac_registers (err 0)
[   12.809608] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_txpwr_idx_to_dbm (err 0)
[   12.809615] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_init_bb_rf_reg_def (err 0)
[   12.809620] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_save_adda_registers (err 0)
[   12.809623] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_pi_mode_switch (err 0)
[   12.809629] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_dm_init_edca_turbo (err 0)
[   12.809633] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_path_a_fill_iqk_matrix (err 0)
[   12.809636] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723ae_firmware_selfreset (err 0)
[   12.809640] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_mac_setting_calibration (err 0)
[   12.809646] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_query_bb_reg (err 0)
[   12.809649] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_rf_serial_read (err 0)
[   12.809654] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_dm_init_dynamic_bb_powersaving (err 0)
[   12.809659] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_reload_mac_registers (err 0)
[   12.809663] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_dm_init_dynamic_txpower (err 0)
[   12.809673] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_download_fw (err 0)
[   12.809680] rtl8723ae: Unknown symbol rtl8723_phy_reload_adda_registers (err 0)
```

Also, in the Network settings in System Settings, I see "Wired" and "Proxy connection", but I don't see wireless.

My wireless works in Windows 8 (dual booted).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the non-free Linux firmware package. To install, run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```